# Select column of dataframe with name matching a string in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a large DataFrame that I import from a spreadsheet.  I have the names of several columns that I care about in an array of strings.  How do I select a column of the DataFrame who's name matches the contents of a string?  I would have though that something like this would work

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"], C = 2:5)
colsICareAbout = [":B" ":C"]
df[:A] #This works
df[colsICareAbout[1]] #This doesn't work
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are different than symbols, but they're easy to convert.

```
colsICareAbout = ["B","C"]
df[symbol(colsICareAbout[1])]
```

Mind you it might be better to make the entries in `colsICareAbout` symbols to begin with, but I don't know where your data is coming from.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  I'll see if I can get them to add this as an example in the DataFrames docs -- it seems like a fairly common thing that people would want to do.